# Conditional logic not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

This should be simple but I can't get it to work. I am attempting to check if the value of a hidden input is empty on focus of a textarea in the same form. I don't understand why this does not alert() my message when empty:

```
$("#postbody").focus(function() {
    var inputLength = $("#topicCategory").val().length;
    console.log(inputLength);// outputs 0
    if( inputLength == 0 ) {// condition is true, but code does not run.
        alert("Please select a category to post your question in.");
    }
});
```

Am I missing something here?

I have also tried all sorts of other ways with no luck.

Comment: may be because your browser is blocking the alert.

Comment: It works fine for me ... what browser ?

Comment: Chrome. I think it is being blocked. Now I feel retarded. Checked in Firefox and is working

Comment: Add your html code so we can understand batter

Comment: Try to put the colsole.log inside if condition

Comment: @turtleSack: I don't think we need that sort of inappropriate, derogatory, childish language. The mentally deficient are people, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your conditional statement and it does work.

Since you are expecting a zero, instead of using double equals to check against zero you can use the NOT operator since zero evaluates as falsy.

```
if (!inputLength) {// condition is true, but code does not run.
    console.log("Please select a category to post your question in.");
}
```

[Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching onfocus handler function for the textarea postbody before it is created in DOM. You have to attach the handler function inside JQuery.ready() function which ensures the code inside it is executed after the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#postbody").focus(function () {
    var inputLength = $("#topicCategory").val().length;
    console.log(inputLength);// outputs 0
    if( inputLength == 0 ) {// condition is true, but code does not run.
        alert("Please select a category to post your question in.");
    }
    });
});
```